# Error while trying to parse a YouTube search feed

Tags: php, xml, youtube

I'm using SimpleXML to parse a YouTube search feed. I want to get the first result in the feed after searching for a term. Right now my code looks like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);

// Include needed files
require_once "config.php";

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=V.I.P.+KE%24HA&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2');

print_r($xml->entry[0]->link);
```

The output for the code above is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => alternate
            [type] => text/html
            [href] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TveGAmLdn8k&feature=youtube_gdata
        )

)
```

How can i get the value of "href" ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to access the attributes:

```
echo $xml->entry[0]->link["href"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method to a SimpleXML Object